# why ruby base64 different from others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding, base64

I have a string

```
\b\xC0\xB3\xB9\xDD\xFC\x1C\x12XBalance debited with 62.0 Expiry Date is 09-11-2016 09:10:00 Remaining Balance is 1490.0\x1A\x0FDebited Balance\"XBalance debited with 62.0 Expiry Date is 09-11-2016 09:10:00 Remaining Balance is 1490.0(\x99\x9C\xCE\xBF\x05
```

When I encode online sites like https://www.base64encode.org/ it returns

```
XGJceEMwXHhCM1x4QjlceEREXHhGQ1x4MUNceDEyWEJhbGFuY2UgZGViaXRlZCB3aXRoIDYyLjAgRXhwaXJ5IERhdGUgaXMgMDktMTEtMjAxNiAwOToxMDowMCBSZW1haW5pbmcgQmFsYW5jZSBpcyAxNDkwLjBceDFBXHgwRkRlYml0ZWQgQmFsYW5jZVwiWEJhbGFuY2UgZGViaXRlZCB3aXRoIDYyLjAgRXhwaXJ5IERhdGUgaXMgMDktMTEtMjAxNiAwOToxMDowMCBSZW1haW5pbmcgQmFsYW5jZSBpcyAxNDkwLjAoXHg5OVx4OUNceENFXHhCRlx4MDU=
```

But when same string encoded by ruby with Base64.encode64(above_string) then I got:

```
CMCzud38HBJYQmFsYW5jZSBkZWJpdGVkIHdpdGggNjIuMCBFeHBpcnkgRGF0\nZSBpcyAwOS0xMS0yMDE2IDA5OjEwOjAwIFJlbWFpbmluZyBCYWxhbmNlIGlz\nIDE0OTAuMBoPRGViaXRlZCBCYWxhbmNlIlhCYWxhbmNlIGRlYml0ZWQgd2l0\naCA2Mi4wIEV4cGlyeSBEYXRlIGlzIDA5LTExLTIwMTYgMDk6MTA6MDAgUmVt\nYWluaW5nIEJhbGFuY2UgaXMgMTQ5MC4wKJmczr8F\n
```

I am not sure why this is produce different string, also when I tried to decode by Base64.decode64(output_from_online) that not produce original string(added extra slash in outputs like \b\xC0\xB3\xB9\xDD\xFC\x1C\x12XBalance...) but when I tried to decode ruby it returns original string

anyone let me know why there are two different encodings? and how I can encode same as online available with ruby

How can I found original string with single slash as that is the only requirment

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you put that string in Ruby inside double quotes, the interpreter parses it and interprets the backslash sequences as escape characters (see the Escape Characters section on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_strings.htm). The page you're using doesn't interpret escape characters.

If you want to include the backslashes on the encoded/decoded text, you could use single quotes in Ruby, which don't parse escape characters (except for \').

Comment: But in that case it return string littile bit different from online: XGJceEMwXHhCM1x4QjlceEREXHhGQ1x4MUNceDEyWEJhbGFuY2UgZGViaXRl\nZCB3aXRoIDYyLjAgRXhwaXJ5IERhdGUgaXMgMDktMTEtMjAxNiAwOToxMDow\nMCBSZW1haW5pbmcgQmFsYW5jZSBpcyAxNDkwLjBceDFBXHgwRkRlYml0ZWQg\nQmFsYW5jZVwiWEJhbGFuY2UgZGViaXRlZCB3aXRoIDYyLjAgRXhwaXJ5IERh\ndGUgaXMgMDktMTEtMjAxNiAwOToxMDowMCBSZW1haW5pbmcgQmFsYW5jZSBp\ncyAxNDkwLjAoXHg5OVx4OUNceENFXHhCRlx4MDU=\n     Noticed that \n in string and when decode this by ruby it will not same as original it have double slash like \\b\\xC0\\xB3\\xB9\\xDD\\xFC\\x1C\\x12XBalance debited with 62.

Comment: How can I found original string with single slash as that is the only requirment

Comment: @Thorin `encode64` adds newlines every 60 characters. You can use `strict_encode64` instead.

Comment: Okay but how I can decode string back to original ? it always return string with double slashs not single

Comment: @Thorin: Your comment is very unclear. What do you mean by "how I can decode string back to original"? You use the base64 library of whatever platform you want to decode the string on. What do you mean by "it always return string with double slashs not single"? There are no slashes in the example string you posted. Are you talking about a different string?

Comment: José Ernesto Lara   The String I have added in question when I encode it with strict_encode64 like @Stefan suggest but when I decode that encoded string again it returns \\b\\xC0\\xB3\\xB9\\xDD\\xFC\\x1C\\x12XBalance...  type string you see that there are two backward slash instead of one like original, I tried all these operation on irb

Comment: Hey Thorin, what are you using to print the string? The double backslash is an internal representation of Ruby (and other languages, like C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript), it's showing you the slashes escaped. If you use puts to print your string, for example, it will show a single backslash. Or if you save it to a file.